# How do I re-attach to an existing Java EE session

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

When someone comes into with a servlet request to my application, a session is created. I am creating a unique ID for this connection and return it to the client.

When the client comes back with that unique ID, i want to re-attach them to their existing session regardless of what comes in with the jsessionid.

Ideas?

Comment: Curious to know what parameters you would want to use to identify request is from same client?

Comment: @Nambari The unique key that I returned the first time.

Comment: I think one way is use sessionListeners to have custom map of sessions. http://www.coderanch.com/t/365859/Servlets/java/session-object-session-ID

Comment: @Nambari That's close, but because it doesn't give me access to the request, I can't know which session to re-attach to. Cool, though, I'll file that away.

Comment: I think what you may need to do is, create new session, but get session content from previous session and populate to this session. Clear previous session. I haven't tested this though.

Comment: I couldn't get it clear, but I think you need utilize cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your real requirement is here, but it appears to me as if you want to have a control over the session id, and not rely on the container generated `jsessionid`.

To me the simplest solution would be to customize the session identifier used by your Application Server / Web Container. All servers provide this facility, so basically I would implement it in the following manner:

1. Customize your server to use what ever name you want for the session identifying parameter, if you don't like `jsessionid`.
2. Create a session custom session repository or manager, which will manage sessions for your container. This step will be specific to your server, basically you are ensuring that all your server instances use a central repository where they need to lookup / update sessions. This will take care of multi server deployments, without the need for sticky session based load balancing.
3. Leave the work of creating / updating / re-attaching / deleting sessions to the container. Its built to do that.

Now if you think this seems like a lot of configuration, and very specific to the container, I agree with you. But I also think there is no point in repeating functionality that's already there (DRY).

If I read your question and try to break it down into features, its basically exactly how servers handle Http Sessions, using an identified conventionally called `jsessionid`. So it feels like a natural solution to customize the existing functionality.

Hope this helps. If I misunderstood your question, please do let me know.

Answer (score 5):

That's the job of the application/web container. The application/web container by default associates the required session. I don't think containers will provide API's which can be used for looking up for sessions.

Your use case suggests that you don't want the app/web container to create a session and you want to manage it by yourself. In this case, each request is a stateless from app/web container perspective. You can manage a session for yourself by using a map (a distributed one if clustered environment). You will have lot of stuff to manage, security, persistance, timeout and lot more.

Comment: I would second this...  You either need to let the web container handle session management for you, or assume that responsibility in code yourself.

Comment: And you really don't want to do that yourself. Someone spent a lot of time creating, testing, and debugging that container. They have a large bug database chronicling all the various ways people have broken things over the years. You'll need to discover all of that for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Get the session id using the Session object.

Take a map, TreeMap. SessionId would be the key, your uniqueId would be the value.

For every request before check the map contains the SessionId, if not present put the key-value into the map.

Make sure that the TreeMap you use is static.

Finally when you are invalidating the session, remove the key from the TreeMap.

Reason to use TreeMap is because it does not allow null values. Hence even by mistake you cannot insert null values, but if the performance is an issue, go with HashMap, which is better compared to TreeMap.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the existing session times out on the server before a request is received, and not because user logged out.

Since the session will be deleted and its data lost, you have to make a copy of the session data in order to allow automatic "session continuation".

**NOTE** Untested code, just an idea.

The idea is to watch for `HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed()` event:

```
class SessionDataBackupListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    private Map<String,Object> oldSessions = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
      final Session s = event.getSession();
      if (s.getAttribute("logOut")) {
        // Session was closed on-command, nothing to do.
        return;
      }

      // Session (probably) timed-out.
      Object sessionData = extractSessionData(s);

      // This should go into some kind of singleton DAO object.
      oldSessions.put(s.getAttribute("uniqueId"), sessionData);
    }
}
```

Your log-out handler would look like:

```
  public void logOut(HttpServletRequest req) {
    final Session s = req.getSession();
    final String userId = s.getParameter("userId");
    // Log the user out.

    // Mark the session was closed on-command.
    s.setAttribute("logOut", Boolean.TRUE);
  }
```

Your log-in handler would look like:

```
  public void logIn(HttpServletRequest req) {
    final String uniqueId = s.getParameter("uniqueId");
    Session s = req.getSession(false);

    // User returning after time-out?
    if (s == null && uniqueId != null) {
      // Create new session...
      s = req.getSession(true);

      // ...assign it the same uniqueId...
      s.setAttribute("uniqueId", uniqueId);

      // ...and put back old session data.
      copyDataToSession(s, getOldSessionData(uniqueId));
    }
    else {
      // User logging in as usual.
    }
  }
```

`getOldSessionData(final String uniqueId)` would look up the singleton DAO object for earlier session.